# changing date format of column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column of dates in a pyspark dataframe in the format 01-01-1999 (dd-mm-yyyy)and I would like to change the date format of the entire column to 1999-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd). Any help?

Comment: `datetime` and `date` in Python have no format, they're binary values. Either you have a string instead of date, or you confuse how the `date` is displayed on some UI with the actual way a `date` is stored.

Comment: see [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html#pyspark-sql-functions-to-date) function in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark we have this function:

```
date_format(dateExpr,format)
```

It converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format specified by the date format given by the second argument.
You can try ths one:

```
df.select(date_format('your_column_date', "yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
```

Comment: This just returns a null value.

Comment: can you show me your code

Comment: [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html#pyspark-sql-functions-date-format) can only format if it is already in default format ('yyyy-MM-dd').